# show bootstrap 4.4 navbar content to the right side of screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add some icons to my bootstrap 4 navbar, and I need that these icons are showed under the menu toggler hamburger button, the icons are an account icon to link to the account page of woocommerce, a cart icon that have a badge displayed only if there are items in the cart and the flags of the translation plugin. I've tried to achieve my objective, the text-right boostrap class, the float-right and the justify-content-end, but none of these classes will put the content under the toggler button on the right side of the screen. Is there a fix to my code?

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top bs-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-inner">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
        <?php $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod('custom_logo'), 'full' ); ?>
        <?php if( $logo ): ?>
          <img class="navbar-logo" src="<?php echo $logo[0]; ?>" id="" width="auto" height="60">
        <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding:0;">
          <!-- Search icon - beta-->
          <!-- <a class="nav-search-icon" href="#searchForm" data-toggle="modal">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </a> -->
          <!-- Hamburger menu button -->
          <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expand="false" aria-label="<?php _e('Toggle Navigation'); ?>">
            <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding:0;">
          <!-- Menu cart icon -->
          <?php $items = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count; ?>
          <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <?php if( $items > 0 ): ?>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger cart-menu-badge"><?php echo $items; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </a>
          <!-- account icon -->
          <a class="nav-account-icon" href="<?php echo wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ); ?>">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
          </a>
          <!-- translate flags -->
          <?php echo do_shortcode('[gtranslate]'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-content" id="navbar-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

              <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                    'menu'        => 'Menu',
                    'container'      => false,
                    'depth'          => 2,
                    'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                    'walker'         => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(),
                    'fallback_cb'    => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback',
                ) );
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

I'm using a sidepanel menu, so the items will be showed only if the user clicks on the navbar toggler button. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the icons within the same container as hamburger. And position the icons using class col